# Error with opening a connection with COM port in C/C++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am using a Windows 8.1 Pro machine. OK and I am trying to open a COM port connection of my serial device. My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(void)
{
     HANDLE hcomm;
     char *comPort = "COM6";
     hcomm = CreateFile(comPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
                        OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
     if(hcomm = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {
           printf("Connection Failed...\n");
     }
     else
          printf("Connection Succeded....\n");
         //return hcomm;
     }
}
```

But this code didn't work for me. Please give some suggestion where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: What did you mean by `didn't work` ?

Comment: Thanks Jarod for replay,I really don't understand where i am getting wrong here..My syntax and program is correct.. Is it window's version problem..?? It returns invalid handle value there..

Comment: BTW, it should be `const char *comPort = "COM6";`

Comment: Yes you are correct.. I tried this program on mingw and vc++ compiler also..but hard luck..

Comment: `CreateFile` take as first argument `LPCTSTR lpFileName` and `LPCTSTR =  const char*` or `const wchar_t*` depending on `_UNICODE`, Did you try `L"COM6"` to use wide char ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it..but didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of GetLastError(). GetLastError() == 0 is success.

Also your `if` condition is re-initializing hcomm to an invalid handle. Note the change from assignment to comparison operator in the `if` condition. Please change your code to below and see if it resolves your problem:

```
if(hcomm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Handle creation failed with error %d", GetLastError());
}
else {
    printf("Handle creation successful");
}
```

Comment: Yes mbaxi, I have checked it with GetLastError(), I was consistantly getting the 0 error code.

Comment: Jarod42 - I don't have enough reputation to make a comment on question, however I seem to be able to add a comment to a comment.

Comment: @mbaxi: Your second sentence should be the OP's error: `=` vs `==`. I suggest to edit your answer to clearly state the OP's error and remove the question part.